# Adaptive Server connection failed: Error with using pymssql

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, pymssql

I can use `sqlcmd` to connect to SQL Server:

```
sqlcmd -S xxxxxmssqlserver.database.windows.net,1433 -U xxxadministrator -P thxxxxx
```

However, it doesn't work when I use Python script.

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='xxxxxxmssqlserver.database.windows.net', user='mradministrator', password='thxxxx', database='AdventureWorks')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName,COUNT(soh.SalesOrderID) AS OrderCount FROM SalesLT.Customer AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS soh ON c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName ORDER BY OrderCount DESC;')
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]) + " " + str(row[2])
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The error msg is

> [testadmin@vic1-deployment]$ python test.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 3, in 
> conn = pymssql.connect(server='xxxxmssqlserver.database.windows.net', user='xxxadministrator@xxxxmssqlserver', password='xxxxx', database='Master')
>
> File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
> pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed xxxxxmssqlserver.database.windows.net)\n')

Environment checks per suggestions below! [Environment Requirements](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/azure.html)

```
[testadmin@vic1 deployment]$ tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/freetds/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 5.0
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

I have used the following in connection parameters:

```
user='xxxadministrator@xxxxmssqlserver'
database='Master'
```

But I don't know how to check `TDS protocol version` and if `FreeTDS is built with SSL support`. However, I can see `TDS version` is `5.0` from `tsql -C` output.

Comment: What's the specific error?  Does this help? https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/azure.html

Comment: When using pymssql, the `user` should be `xxxadministrator@servername`.

Comment: @LeonYue Not working.

Comment: @squillman I have attached the specific error.

Comment: @cdhit Please check you pymssql environment here: https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/azure.html

Comment: @LeonYue I have added additional info about the environment. Not working still!

Comment: @cdhit may I ask why  you don't use `pyodbc`? Actually,  `pymssql` is not used frequently.

Comment: @LeonYue I used this approach to isolate a connection issue of the connection from Ansible ‘mssql_db’ module to ‘sql server’ because I guess the Ansible use python module to connect to ‘sql server’.

Comment: @LeonYue I had an issue `has no attribute connect` when trying `pyodbc`.